# ios remote access

Tags: ios, remote-access

Is there a way to access my iOS device through some type of virtual machine or graphical user interface in a similar way that I could access my servers? My device is currently jailbroken. I don't know if this helps. It is more convenient for me to control my device through my device with my mac.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is a VNC (Virtual Network Computing) server application for your phone, where the desktop would be the client.  I don't have an iPhone, but if I search the app store for "VNC", these two applications show up near the top of the list:

- [VNC Viewer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vnc-viewer-remote-desktop/id352019548) - Remote Desktop by RealVNC
- [VNC Server](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vnc-server/id1616886311) (Also by RealVNC).

You want the "server" application for your phone, and the "client" application for your desktop.

You can read more about VNC [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).  It is an open-source protocol, and many server/client applications are available that run on that protocol, so you may be able to find a better one for your platform(s).

Doing some searching, I also see a few articles that indicate that the iPhone is compatible with Microsoft Phone-Link, which might be easier to set up if you are already invested in the Microsoft ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you can get a shell working then it should be possible. 
Doing a quick google search I saw there are already solutions to SSH into an iOS phone (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/termius-ssh-client/id549039908?mt=8). 
Maybe try that :)

Comment: I have tried this application and it is not as good as advertised. I was really looking for a GUI application instead of something on the CLI.